# Intellij IDEA: How to change build directory?

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone happen to know how to change the build directory name in Intellij IDEA (11 or 12)? The default name is `out`, I want it to be `target`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can find the setting here

File [Menu] > Project Structure > Modules [List] > Path [Tab] > Use module compile output path [Option]

Comment: Can this be done as a general setting rather than a project/module setting? It will be cumbersome to apply this setting everytime a new project is imported into IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4):

In Intellij IDEA 13.1.4, do:

1. File [menu]
2. Project Structure [option]
3. Project Settings [section]
4. Project [tab]
5. Project compiler output [text field]

Answer (score 0):

For: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3

Add to build.gradle(Project)

```
  allprojects {

        buildDir = "C:/path/to/build/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"

     repositories {........
```

And allow your anti-virus to run .gradle or you'll get Exploit.PayloadProcessBlock